# UIViewController default title font settings

Tags: iphone

Anybody know the default settings of uiviewcontroller's title? Like text color, shadow etc..

Comment: have a look on Interface Builder.

Answer (score 8):

A good trick for this, in the future, is to take a screenshot of the element you're trying to replicate and then just try and copy it side by side in photoshop until the pixels look the same!

The navigation item title is Helvetica-Bold with as size of 20.0f. Also, the shadow is 1px and black, with an opacity of about 0.5.